Permission classification by Android version
I want to use the READ_MEDIA_IMAGES permission in the app starting from Android API version 33 or higher, and if it is lower than 33, I want to use the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. What should I do?
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />


What have you done in code?

Android API versions 33 and higher have both the READ_MEDIA_IMAGES and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions, while versions lower than 33 only have the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.

I'm not talking about what permissions you added to the AndroidManifest.xml file. But rather what logic do you have in place inside your application?

Android API versions 33 and higher have both the READ_MEDIA_IMAGES and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions Nonsense. They can only go for READ_MEDIA_*.
